# Size of button in tablerow is not correct. (Android)

Tags: android, button, size, tablerow

I'm writing an Android application. Here is it's XML layout :

```
 <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_gravity="left|top|bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"

>

     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/centerlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_gravity="left|right|top|bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="120dip"    >

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >



    <TableRow>
         <Button android:text="Button" 
             android:layout_column="0"
            android:id="@+id/bookmarkbutton" 
            android:layout_width="230dip" 
            android:layout_height="30dip" 

            android:background="@drawable/red_btn"
            android:padding="14dp" 
           ></Button>


    </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>

   </LinearLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

and if I run it, it displays the following screen:
[image]

But when I add android:layout_gravity="left" to the "Button", the button size decreases and shows :
[image]

Please note if I change the width of button by android:layout_width="30dip", it shows small buttons,
[image]

but If I change it to bigger sizes, it does not apply the size correctly and the max width is the same as second image.

Finally If I add a new textview to it, via

```
ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_gravity="left|top|bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"



>

         <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/centerlayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_gravity="left|right|top|bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="120dip"


        >

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >



  <TableRow>
         <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/subjecttext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="10dip"
        android:padding="14dp" 
        />    
        </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
         <Button android:text="Button" 
             android:layout_column="0"
            android:id="@+id/bookmarkbutton" 
            android:layout_width="20dip" 
            android:layout_height="30dip" 
            android:background="@drawable/black_btn"
            android:padding="14dp" 
           ></Button>


    </TableRow>





</TableLayout>

        </LinearLayout>



        </ScrollView>
```

It displays the following image, and the size of button no longer is changeable.  Would you please tell me what's wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use LinearLayout instead of TableLayout. Here your code with LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top|bottom|right" 
    android:layout_marginTop="80dip" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dip" 
    android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dip">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/centerlayout" 
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left|right|top|bottom" 
                android:layout_marginRight="20dip" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" 
                android:layout_marginBottom="120dip">
        <TextView android:text="Very long text in textview" 
                android:textSize="20sp" android:id="@+id/subjecttext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:lineSpacingExtra="10dip" 
                android:padding="14dp" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/bookmarkbutton" 
                android:background="@drawable/red_btn" 
                android:text="Button" 
                android:padding="14dp" 
                android:layout_height="30dip"
                android:layout_width="20dip">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And Screenshot:

[image]

Hope, it help you!.

I actually see that your buttons in the button of screen have cropped text. Is this a second problem?

Bellow I attached screenshot with code:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top|bottom|right" 
    android:layout_marginTop="80dip" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dip" 
    android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dip">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/centerlayout" 
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left|right|top|bottom" 
                android:layout_marginRight="20dip" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" 
                android:layout_marginBottom="120dip">
        <TextView android:text="Very long text in textview" 
                android:textSize="20sp" android:id="@+id/subjecttext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:lineSpacingExtra="10dip" 
                android:padding="14dp" />
        <Button android:text="Button" 
                android:background="@drawable/red_btn" 
                android:id="@+id/button1" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine. You saved me a lot of time.